# How to use react router js without webpack in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm new to reactjs. I'm struggling to set route change. Is there any simple solutions for router change event without webpack?

```
var PageOne = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
      return (
        <h2>Page 1</h2>
      );
    }  
});
var PageTwo = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
      return (
        <h2>Page 2</h2>
      );
    }  
});
var PageThree = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
      return (
        <h2>Page 3</h2>
      );
    }  
});
```

Comment: could you share some code, so we can see what you have tried already?

Comment: @user1120808.. i have updated my question

Comment: Can you provide some more information about how you're trying to render those pages? You might also find this useful https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/v1.0.0-rc3/docs/guides/basics/RouteConfiguration.md

Answer (score 1):

You can use `HashRouter` from `react-router-dom` which is easier to use (in my view) and works even after reloading the page.
Here an example:

- First, install React Router v4: `npm install --save react-router-dom`
- Then in your index or parent component use this code:

```
import { HashRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
const App = () => (
  <HashRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route path='/page1' component={PageOne} />
      <Route path='/page2' component={PageTwo} />
      <Route path='/page3' component={PageThree} />
    </Switch>
  </HashRouter>
)
```

- Here is an example for your nav component:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
const Nav = () => (
  <div>
    <Link to='/page1'>Page1</Link>
    <Link to='/page2'>Page2</Link>
    <Link to='/page3'>Page3</Link>
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple mechanics of React-router is below:

```
import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

// inside your parent component add routs
<Switch>
   <Route path="/page1" exact render={<PageOne>} />
   <Route path="/page2" exact render={<PageTwo>} />
   <Route path="/page3" exact render={<PageThree>} />
</Switch>

// connect your parent component with Router
<Router history={history}>
  <AppConnected />
</Router>
```